# Select the value/text of an <a> element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got these 3 links

```
<a id="ajaxed" href="#"  value="213">WTF</a>
<a id="ajaxed" href="#"  value="213">DUDE</a>
<a id="ajaxed" href="#"  value="213">SRSLY</a>
```

And I want to parse the value `attribute`. I'm using this script but it always return `null`.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#ajaxed').on('click',function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Also I tried parse the text and it only works for the first one `<a>`.
The fiddle of that one: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dzasusxp/18/
What am I doing wrong? It seems kinda ok for me...

Comment: You have 3 elements with the same `id`?

Comment: you can use attribute like `data-value="213"`  with <a> tag

Comment: IDs are implemented via a fast lookup dictionary in browsers, so it only stores a single DOM element for each ID. This means jQuery ID selectors can only *ever* select the first matching element. Use class instead of IDs for multiple matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are has to be unique per element in a page and also `.val()` should only be applied on form elements. To get the value you should consider the `.attr()` method.

To get this working you should change your `id` attribute to `class`.

```js
$('.ajaxed').click(function(){
  var val = $(this).attr('value');
  alert(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="ajaxed" href="#"  value="213">WTF</a>
<a class="ajaxed" href="#"  value="213">DUDE</a>
<a class="ajaxed" href="#"  value="213">SRSLY</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `id` attribute should be always uniqe in HTML.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_id.asp).

Use a `class` instead the `id`.

See the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzasusxp/21/)

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

id = name [CS]
This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.
class = cdata-list [CS]
This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ajaxed` `id` to `class` and following code work fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.ajaxed').on('click',function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
     alert(value);
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dzasusxp/20/

Answer (score 0):

$('#ajaxed') will not be returning array of 'a' tag elements. It returns the first matched element. Try to give different ID's or same class name, as below

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.ajaxed').on('click',function() {
var value = $(this).text();
alert(value);
});
});
```

```html
<a class="ajaxed" href="#"  value="213">WTF</a>
<a class="ajaxed" href="#"  value="213">DUDE</a>
<a class="ajaxed" href="#"  value="213">SRSLY</a>
```

See difference between id and class [ID/CSS](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Answer (score -1):

The attribute `value` in an `a` tag is an invalid attribute. The method `.value()` takes focus for form fields. If you really want to use this attribute in an a tag, use the method `.attr("value")` instead of `.value()`.

Answer (score -1):

try `$el.txt()` to get `el.innerText`